# Я пытался установить metasploit на Ubuntu увы безуспешно(

Tags: ubuntu

когда я запускаю терминал у меня вылазит вот такая ошибка:

> bash: /home/yan/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
>   /usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory bash:
>   /home/yan/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

Метасплоит пытался ставить вот от сюда: 
https://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt

Comment: Не редактируйте конфиг файлы на винде - `\r` это подарок от вашего нотпада-вордпада-ворда-итд

Answer (score 2):

Через 6 часов проведеных за компом у меня получилось.
Первая команда: cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
А потом нужно удалить строку из файла /etc/bash.bashrc
Для этого запустите файл от имени администратора.
Вот как будет выглядеть файл bash.bashrc:

```
type rvm >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo ${PATH} | 
 export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
```